# What happens when creating a tcp connection out of local network

Tags: tcp

For example:

```
we have 2 computers, both out of NAT
computer1 is hosting a tcp-service which computer2 wants to connect to
computer2 knows the IP of computer1 and the port of the service
```

In LAN it would be clear to me how they connect, but how does it look like out of a local network? Both may be behind different ISP's, how do they know where to send their packages and which way do they actually go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IP datagrams always travel from/to hosts on the same network. So, if you understand how this works, then the only missing piece in the puzzle are routers.

A router is a kind of special host connected to two or more local networks. Routers receive datagrams from one of its local networks and based on destination IP address and routing tables, forward them to some other local network. Routers are hosts that make datagrams "hop" from one local network to the next one.

```
Source Host -- (local network) --> Router -- (local network) --> Router --> (local network) --> Destination Host
```

One important point to mention is that these local networks are not only Ethernet (LAN) networks, so how packets travel from host to host on each local networks depends on the layer 2 protocol being used on that network.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I searched for! Especially the part with the hops. So when I run traceroute to google.com (I am from germany) I get 15 hops. The first hop is obviously my router at home. So the second hop would be a router (provided by the ISP) covering my local area (like one or two towns), after that a router that covers multiple of the routers before, until two ISP's exchange (for example at the DE-CIX) and then the whole thing happens backwards wherever the DNS leaded me to. Is that right?

Comment: Exactly, big ISPs usually connect at [Internet Exchange Points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_exchange_point) and routing at that level is based on [Autonomous Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(Internet)) and the [Border Gateway Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Border_Gateway_Protocol)

Answer (score 0):

If a host must send something to another host on a different network, it sends the layer-3 packet, addressed to the destination host, encapsulated in a layer-2 frame, addressed to its configured gateway (router). The gateway is the LAN host that knows how to forward packets to other networks.